# node.js calculating sub urls number

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i'm very new to node.js, was trying to do as in the example below, but there is a problem with my code that I couldn't figure it out

example if

/add/1/1 -> should show in the page 2

/add/2/3 -> should show in the page 5

/sub/1/1 -> should show in the page 0

/sub/5/2 -> should show in the page 3

```js
var http = require('http')


http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var parts = req.url.split("/"),
        op = parseInt(parts[1]),
        a = parseInt(parts[2], 10),
        b = parseInt(parts[3], 10);

    var result = op ? op(a,b) : "Error";


    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Tybe': 'text/plain'});
    res.end("" + result);
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: What are you getting? Why are you trying to parse the op as integer?

Comment: @GershonPapi thank you, your question really helped me, it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `op` is not a function. You must use `eval(op)`.

The rest of the code (accessing parameters) can be easily done using [Express](https://expressjs.com/)

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/:op/:firstParam/:secondParam', function (req, res) {
  var op = req.params.op
  var a  = parseInt(req.params.firstParam)
  var b  = parseInt(req.params.secondParam)

  var result = eval(op)(a,b)
  res.send('result: ' + result)
})

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

function sub(a, b) {
  return a - b
}

app.listen(3000)
```

(**Note**: this example code will not work if you pass undefiend functions like `foo` i.e. http://localhost:3000/foo/8/2 . Add proper checks when calling `eval(op)` based on your specific needs)